# perform task at a user defined time

Tags: java, timer, jtextfield

I need to get a time from the user and schedule my task at that particular time.  For getting the time from the user, I displayed the current system time in a JTextField so that the user can edit it easily if wanted.

```
private JTextField time;    
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
            time = new JTextField(date);
            time.setBounds(452, 251, 200, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(time);
            time.setColumns(10);
```

But if i do this, I am unable to extract the modified time back in my code. If I extract it by using  `time.getText()` it is in the string format. and i cannot use it in my scheduler

Is there any other way of getting a user defined time in the date format itself?

Also, what is the proper way of delaying my task till the specified time? Its a one-time task, not a repetitive task.

Comment: `time.setBounds(452, 251, 200, 20);` Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.

Comment: What format/type does the scheduler expect? `SimpleDateFormat` can be used to _parse_ a date `String`...

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for that. could you suggest a link or some source where i can learn how to use layout managers? I am new to java

Comment: See the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.

Comment: @Reimeus  can `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` be used in my case?

Comment: You should be using a `Swing Timer` instead of `java.util.Timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html#constructor_summary) in a `JSpinner`.

[image: Spinner demo]

For more information see [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html).

Comment: thanks...  could you please also suggest a proper way to delay my task till the specified time?

Comment: One answer per question (ask a new question specific to that).